# How to disable submit button until form is filled and valid in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created a `Contact Us` form and the submit button is disabled. The submit button is only enabled if all fields are filled and the entries are valid.

Currently, my issue is after I entered all the fields with valid entries, the button still not show up. However, after entering in all the fields with valid input and I click on the `name` or `email` input box and type a character at the end, then the `submit` button becomes active. I think there is some async issue with my `checkValidation` function and I am not sure how to fix it.

[image]

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import '../css/ContactUs.css';

class ContactUs extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    
        this.state = {
             name: '',
             email: '',
             birthDate: '',
             emailConsent: false,
             disableSubmitButton: true
        }
    }

    changeHandler = e => {
        const nameSelect = e.target.name
        const value = e.target.type === 'checkbox' ? e.target.checked : e.target.value;
        this.setState({
            [nameSelect]: value
        })
        this.checkValidation()
    }

    checkValidation = e => {
        
        const { name, email, birthDate, emailConsent, disableSubmitButton } = this.state
        const validCharacters = /^[a-zA-Z ]+$/
        const validEmail = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
        const today = new Date();
        const birthdate = new Date(birthDate);
        if (
            !(name.length === 0) &&
            name.match(validCharacters) &&
            !(email.length === 0) &&
            validEmail.test(email) &&
            emailConsent === true &&
            birthdate < today
        ) {
            this.setState({
            disableSubmitButton: false
        }, () => console.log('passed'))}
    }

    clearHandler = e => {
        this.setState({
             name: '',
             email: '',
             birthDate: '',
             emailConsent: false
        })
        console.log('clicked clear')
    }

    handleSubmit = e => {
        const { name, email, birthDate, emailConsent } = this.state
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log(this.state);
        axios.post('https://my-json-server.typicode.com/xxxxx/users', {name : name, email: email, birthDate: birthDate, emailConsent: emailConsent })
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
        })
    }

    render() {
        const { name, email, birthDate, emailConsent, disableSubmitButton } = this.state
        
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <h1>Contact Us</h1>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <label>
                        Name
                        <input 
                            className="text"
                            name="name"
                            type="text"
                            value={name}
                            onChange={this.changeHandler}
                        />
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        Email
                        <input 
                            className="text"
                            name="email"
                            type="email"
                            value={email}
                            onChange={this.changeHandler}
                        />
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        Birth Date
                        <input 
                            className="text"
                            name="birthDate"
                            type="date"
                            value={birthDate}
                            onChange={this.changeHandler}
                        />
                    </label>
                    <label className="checkbox">
                        <input 
                            
                            name="emailConsent"
                            type="checkbox"
                            checked={emailConsent}
                            onChange={this.changeHandler}
                        />
                        I agree to be contact via email.
                    </label>
                    <div className="float-right">
                        <button className="clear" type="button" onClick={this.clearHandler}>Clear</button>
                        <input disabled={disableSubmitButton} className={disableSubmitButton ? 'submit-inactive' : 'submit'} type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default ContactUs
```

Comment: It’s not your bug, but I notice your `checkValidation` function is defined like `checkValidation = e => {…}`, taking an `e` parameter. This `e` parameter is never passed to it or used, so you should write `checkValidation = () => {…}` or `checkValidation() {…}`.

Answer (score 2):

I guessing this is because the change event is fired only when one leaves the input. Try to replace, in the render method, `onChange` by `onInput`.

Comment: In plain JavaScript you would be right, but in React, `onChange` actually works the same as `onInput` – it listens for `input` events. So `onChange` can’t be the problem.

Comment: Oops sorry about that, I didn't know, thank you for pointing it out

Answer (score 1):

`this.setState(…)` is asynchronous so, in `changeHandler` function `this.checkValidation()` is executed after the state has been updated. This is why it only works when you add one character after the form beeing valid.

Comment: How do I fix it so that the users don't have to do that extra step and have the submit button show up?

Comment: You could add `this.checkValidation()` inside `this.setState(…)` 2nd parameter function (where you have console.log in `checkValidation` declaration). Or, probably better, as the  [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) suggests use `componentDidUpdate()`

Comment: Thanks, I use the componentDidUpdate and it works. I also need to make some update on the if statement in order to make it works. I posted my solution here. If you find out an easier way to do it, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Someone here suggested me to use `componentDidUpdate` and it works. If you know another way to do it, please let me know. Thanks!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import '../css/ContactUs.css';

class ContactUs extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    
        this.state = {
             name: '',
             email: '',
             birthDate: '',
             emailConsent: false,
             disableSubmitButton: true
        }
    }

    changeHandler = e => {
        const nameSelect = e.target.name
        const value = e.target.type === 'checkbox' ? e.target.checked : e.target.value;
        this.setState({
            [nameSelect]: value
        })
    }

    clearHandler = e => {
        this.setState({
             name: '',
             email: '',
             birthDate: '',
             emailConsent: false
        })
        // console.log('clicked clear')
    }

    handleSubmit = e => {
        const { name, email, birthDate, emailConsent } = this.state
        e.preventDefault()
        // console.log(this.state);
        axios.post('https://my-json-server.typicode.com/xxxxx/users', JSON.stringify({name : name, email: email, birthDate: birthDate, emailConsent: emailConsent }))
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
        })
        alert('Submitted')
    }

    // componentDidUpdate will check all field inputs are complete and valid. If so, it toggles the state of disableSubmitButton and the submit button becomes available and vice versa
    componentDidUpdate() {
        const { name, email, birthDate, emailConsent, disableSubmitButton } = this.state
        const validCharacters = /^[a-zA-Z ]+$/
        const validEmail = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
        const today = new Date();
        const birthdate = new Date(birthDate);
        if (
            disableSubmitButton === true &&
            !(name.length === 0) &&
            name.match(validCharacters) &&
            !(email.length === 0) &&
            validEmail.test(email) &&
            emailConsent === true &&
            birthdate < today &&
            isNaN(birthdate) === false
        ) {
            this.setState({
            disableSubmitButton: false
        })} else if (
            disableSubmitButton === false &&
            ((name.length === 0) ||
            !(name.match(validCharacters)) ||
            (email.length === 0) ||
            !(validEmail.test(email)) ||
            emailConsent !== true ||
            birthdate >= today ||
            isNaN(birthdate) === true)
        ) {
            this.setState({
            disableSubmitButton: true
        })}
    }

    render() {
        const { name, email, birthDate, emailConsent, disableSubmitButton } = this.state
        
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <h1>Contact Us</h1>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <label>
                        Name
                        <input 
                            className="text"
                            name="name"
                            type="text"
                            value={name}
                            onChange={this.changeHandler}
                        />
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        Email
                        <input 
                            className="text"
                            name="email"
                            type="email"
                            value={email}
                            onChange={this.changeHandler}
                        />
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        Birth Date
                        <input 
                            className="text"
                            name="birthDate"
                            type="date"
                            value={birthDate}
                            onChange={this.changeHandler}
                        />
                    </label>
                    <label className="checkbox">
                        <input 
                            
                            name="emailConsent"
                            type="checkbox"
                            checked={emailConsent}
                            onChange={this.changeHandler}
                        />
                        I agree to be contact via email.
                    </label>
                    <div className="float-right">
                        <button className="clear" type="button" onClick={this.clearHandler}>Clear</button>
                        <input disabled={disableSubmitButton} className={disableSubmitButton ? 'submit-inactive' : 'submit'} type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default ContactUs
```